# app stops after scanning qr code

Tags: android, webview, zxing

i wants to automatically navigate to the site after scanning qr code,hear is my code which crashes after scanning qr code.

```
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void QrScanner(View view){


        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        setContentView(mScannerView);

        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView.startCamera();         // Start camera

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here

        Log.e("handler", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
        Log.e("handler", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode)


        WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", rawResult.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the complete code, but I can see that you are calling setContentView twice, and there's no call to the method `QrScanner()`

Comment: You should include a crash log from Logcat, so we can see the error that occurred, and locate in your code why it occurred.